# formatting ISO date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, isodate

I have making an API call and getting response. 
The response has datetime value like this

```
20131107T102103,00+01
```

I guess this is ISO date format. I am not able to format it to human readable format using javascript.

Comment: i am doing this in javascript, i am getting the response from IBM Domino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but it's not exactly the most common form of it.

- This is the compact form.  On the web, we usually see the *extended* form, which is also described in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).
- It's using a comma instead of a decimal in the seconds field.  While either are allowed by the ISO 8601 specification, [most implementations use a decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20699705/634824).
- While ISO 8601 allows for a shortened form of the offset (`+01`), typically this is expressed in the compact form as `+0100`, or in the extended form as `+01:00`.

Nonetheless, the value is ISO 8601 compliant, so it *should* be parseable by most newer browsers.  But it's not.

**Internet Explorer 11**

[image: IE Screenshot]

**Google Chrome 35**

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**Firefox 30**

[image: FireFox Screenshot]

So, what to do then?  You can write a bunch of code to pull out all the individual parts of the string and build a `Date` object yourself, but that's too much work.  Just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  This is one of the leading libraries for parsing and formatting date and time in JavaScript, and it works in all browsers.

```
// parse it to a moment object first
var s = "20131107T102103,00+01";
var m = moment(s + "00","YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss[,]SSZZ");

// then you can output however you like
m.format("...whatever...")

// or perhaps you need a JS Date object
m.toDate()
```

Notice that I still had to add two extra zeros to the offset.  Even moment.js doesn't recognize offsets with only two digits.